# Create Spring @Service instance with @Transactional methods manually from Java

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aop, spring-aop

Let's say there are `@Service` and `@Repository` interfaces like the following:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderDao extends JpaRepository<Order, Integer> {

}

public interface OrderService {

    void saveOrder(Order order);

}

@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private OrderDao orderDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveOrder(Order order) {
        orderDao.save(order);
    }

}
```

This is part of working application, everything is configured to access single database and everything works fine.

Now, I would like to have possibility to **create stand-alone working instance of OrderService with auto-wired OrderDao** using **pure Java** with **jdbcUrl specified in Java code**, something like this:

```
final int tenantId = 3578;
final String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_" + tenantId;
OrderService orderService = someMethodWithSpringMagic(appContext, jdbcUrl);
```

As you can see I would like to introduce **multi-tenant architecture** with **tenant per database** strategy to existing Spring-based application.

Please note that I was able to achieve that **quite easily** before with self-implemented jdbcTemplate-like logic also with JDBC transactions correctly working so this is *very valid task*.

Please also note that I need **quite simple transaction logic** to start transaction, do several requests in service method in scope of that transaction and then commit it/rollback on exception.

Most solutions on the web regarding multi-tenancy with Spring propose specifying concrete persistence units in xml config AND/OR using annotation-based configuration which is **highly inflexible** because in order to add new database url whole application should be stopped, xml config/annotation code should be changed and application started.

So, basically I'm looking for a piece of code which is able to create `@Service` just like Spring creates it internally after properties are read from XML configs / annotations. I'm also looking into using `ProxyBeanFactory` for that, because Spring uses `AOP` to create service instances (so I guess simple good-old re-usable OOP is not the way to go here).

**Is Spring flexible enough** to allow this **relatively simple case** of code reuse?

**Any hints will be greatly appreciated** and if I find complete answer to this question I'll post it here for future generations :)

Comment: HIbernate has [out of the box support for multi tenancy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html), check that out before trying your own. Also about 8 years ago we already wrote a generic solution which was documented [here](https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/) and the code is [here](https://github.com/mdeinum/spring-utils)

Comment: @M.Deinum - **thanks a lot** for fast and helpful response - I'll investigate it now and let you know about the results.

BTW, I read about `Hibernate`'s support for multi-tenancy but unfortunately `JpaRepository` is used at this project and I would like to reuse as much of existing codebase as possible without rewriting it.

Comment: Have you actually read the manual? It is embedded in hibernate and is transparent... Before judging I strongly suggest a read of the manual and links I gave you .

Comment: @M.Deinum I looked at `Hibernate`'s support for multi-tenancy before asking the question and remembered that I found some obstacle in using it. In my previous comment I made a mistake by saying that problem was with `JpaRepository` - I've looked into the documentation again and found out that in order to implement it, I need to specify `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` which only implementation relies on `JNDI` which I'm not very eager to use because of additional complexity (which is unnecessary in my case) - please advise if I'm wrong

Comment: @M.Deinum **regarding your solution** - I thoroughly looked through it and find it really awesome - already used this approach in application and **everything works as a charm** :) I'm also **very fascinated** with `TargetSource` interface in `Spring` - it really provides a lot of flexibility which is sometime so much needed :) Please post your solution as an answer and I'll upvote and accept it after testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HIbernate has [out of the box support for multi tenancy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html), check that out before trying your own. Hibernate requires a [`MultiTenantConnectionProvider`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/MultiTenantConnectionProvider.html) and [`CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver.html) for which there are default implementations out of the box but you can always write your own implementation. If it is only a schema change it is actually pretty simple to implement (execute a query before returning the connection). Else hold a map of datasources and get an instance from that, or create a new instance.

About 8 years ago we already wrote a generic solution which was documented [here](https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/) and the code is [here](https://github.com/mdeinum/spring-utils). It isn't specific for hibernate and could be used with basically anything you need to switch around. We used it for `DataSource`s and also some web related things (theming amongst others).

Comment: Your solution works as a charm - thanks a lot for help!

Comment: I have another related question - did you try using your solution with Tomcat's `Http11NioProtocol` connector (or similar connectors) which provides `asynchronous I/O` functionality? I guess there shouldn't be problems since `I think that Tomcat handles this transparently` and after request data is read from network asynchronously, it's then being handled by single thread, but please advise

Comment: No we haven't, wasn't an issue in those days. So you would be on your own here :)

Answer (score 2):

Creating a transactional proxy for an annotated service is not a difficult task but I'm not sure that you really need it. To choose a database for a tenantId I guess that you only need to concentrate in `DataSource` interface.

For example, with a simple driver managed datasource:

```
public class MultitenancyDriverManagerDataSource extends DriverManagerDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Connection getConnectionFromDriverManager(String url,
            Properties props) throws SQLException {

        Integer tenant = MultitenancyContext.getTenantId();

        if (tenant != null)
            url += "_" + tenant;

        return super.getConnectionFromDriverManager(url, props);
    }

}

public class MultitenancyContext {

    private static ThreadLocal<Integer> tenant = new ThreadLocal<Integer>();

    public static Integer getTenantId() {
        return tenant.get();
    }

    public static void setTenatId(Integer value) {
        tenant.set(value);
    }
}
```

Of course, If you want to use a connection pool, you need to elaborate it a bit, for example using a connection pool per tenant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it's quite similar to @M.Deinum solution from comment and also should solve my problem. I thought about such solutions but usually I'm not very eager of using *shared public static instances*, that's why I thought that maybe there are other solutions which rely on *non-static instances*. However it looks like it's either not possible with Spring or possible with a lot of hassle - please advise

Comment: I liked your solution as well but found solution proposed by M.Deinum (specifying swappable data source as `TargetSource`) more "Spring-like" and that's why I accepted his solution :)